# How to reload (re render) template in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am working on a chat app that supports multiple languages. The basics of the app is working fine however I have small problem when changing chat rooms.

Each room is setup to support 2 languages. When sending a chat message you can choose which language you are sending the message in. This is done by clicking on a small icon of a flag which toggles between the 2 flag icons. The template for this is:

```
<template name="chatBar">
<div id="chatBar" class="input-append input-prepend">
    <form id="chatForm">
        <span class="add-on"><img src="/images/flags-iso/flat/16/{{chatMessageLang}}.png" id="lang"></span>
        <input id="chatMessageLanguage" type="hidden" value="{{chatMessageLang}}">
        <input id="chatMessageTarget" type="hidden" value="{{chatMessageTargetLang}}">
        <input class="input-xxlarge" id="chatMessage" type="text" placeholder="&larr; choose your language and then type your message here&hellip;">
        <button class="btn" id="sendNewMessage" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and is called from another template:

```
<template name="chat">
{{> chatroom}}
<div id="chatWindow">
    <ul>
        {{#each chats}}
        <li class="{{messageClass}} {{_id}}">
            <img src="/images/flags-iso/flat/16/{{langOriginal}}.png">
            {{langTo.flagicon}}
            {{user}}:
            <span class="message" lang="{{langOriginal}}">{{original}}</span>
            {{#if translated}}
            <span class="message" lang="{{langTranslated}}">{{translated}}</span>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if correction}}
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            <span class="friendCorrection">{{correction}}</span>
            {{/if}}
            <span class="messageOptions">{{{messageOptions}}}</span>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
{{> chatBar}}
</template>
```

The problem I have is when I change chatrooms the language options are being retained from the previous chatroom I was in. The code for setting the languages for the chatbar is:

```
Template.chatBar.helpers({
chatMessageLang: function() {
    //return getCurrentChatroomInfo().langFrom.iso;
    return Meteor.user().profile.langNative;
},

chatMessageTargetLang: function() {
    var chatroomLang1 = getCurrentChatroomInfo().langFrom.iso;
    var chatroomLang2 = getCurrentChatroomInfo().langTo.iso;


    if(Meteor.user().profile.langNative == chatroomLang1){
        return chatroomLang2;
    } else {
        return chatroomLang1;
    }
}});

function getCurrentChatroomInfo(){
  return Chatrooms.findOne({_id : Router.current().params['_id']})
}
```

How do I make the variable chatMessageTargetLang reactive to the loaded chatroom (each chatroom has their own route).

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Would [template instance](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst) properties help persist the language per chat room?

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the suggestion. the language of the chatroom themselves is fine. The issue is the chatbar is not reactively reloading when changing chatrooms and so the chatbar has the language setting from the first loaded chatroom.

Comment: The strange thing is that "chatMessageTargetLang" is being updated correctly when changing rooms. But "chatMessageLang" isn't